# Tool tip is not taking line breaks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am having an issue regarding the tooltip I have searched and tried with all possible things available on stackoverflow,

I am using reactjs and creating the element using createElement and applying the tooltip class to enable it.

```
createElement('span', { toolTip, 'data-title': 'line1 <br/> line 2'},numericValue);
```

I have also tried

```
'/n'
'&#013;'
```

Everything appears as it is. data-title is not executing any tag.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used `createElement`, but one thing that I have tried in other tooltips like react-bootstrap, reactstrap is to seperate items into an array.

```
const label = ["Hello", <br />, "world!"]

return <Tooltip label={label} />
```

Hope that helps!